# Insert Graphic into Title Section of beamer Palo Alto

Tags: beamer, graphics

I want to insert a graphic into the title section. On the title page, I want the graphic to be fully visible, then on all the other slides I want it to be more transparent.

When I refer to the title section I mean number 1 of the image.[image]

Comment: Welcome! I assume you want to put stuff over the transparent version of the image? If so, don't. You cannot predict whether the text or whatever will be legible to your audience. Unless you can test on the same computer and with the same projector and screen as you will use to present, it is too risky. What looks almost invisible to you in testing may turn out to look almost opaque to your audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addtobeamertemplate` to add the image inside a TikZ `\node` to control the opacity (since internal calculations are involved two or three runs are needed until the image reaches its final position):

### Update:

The image has to span the full width of the headline but without the sidebar and the height of the image has to be equal to the headline height; in this case, this is the required code to produce the exact size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\makeatletter
\def\Opacity{1}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\ifnum\theframenumber=1\relax\else\def\Opacity{0.3}\fi
  \node[opacity=\Opacity,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
  at ([xshift=0.5\beamer@sidebarwidth]current page.north)
  {\includegraphics[
    width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth\relax,
    height=\beamer@headheight
    ]{test-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother


\title{The Tiltle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### First version

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\def\Opacity{1}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[opacity=\Opacity,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
  at ([yshift=-0.25cm]current page.north)
  {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{image-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{The Tiltle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\def\Opacity{0.4}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}
 
\end{document}
```

If the title page is the first one, you could do

```
\def\Opacity{1}
\addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \ifnum\theframenumber=1\relax\else\def\Opacity{0.5}\fi
  \node[opacity=\Opacity,anchor=north,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
  at ([yshift=-0.25cm]current page.north)
  {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{image-1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

to avoid having to manually change the opacity value.

Comment: Oh, is that what the question means? I didn't get that at all!

Comment: @cft I am not completely sure, but looking at the image in the question, I assumed 1 refered to the headline and 2 to the sidebar.

Comment: @Gonzalo this is very helpful. The graphic I would like to insert will take up the whole title section. Would this work for that situation?

Comment: @Liz Sure, you can adjsut the width and height of your image in the options to `\includegraphics`. Can you upload the actual image to [`imgur`](http://www.imgur.com) so I can provide a real example?

Comment: @Gonzalo this is similiar to what I'll be using. I don't have the exact graphic yet. 
https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3123/2762129665_73aaacd798_b.jpg

Comment: @Liz Should the image span the full paper width? (This might distort the image if the height should be restricted to the headline's height).

Comment: @Gonzalo, it should span the full width, but not interfere with the sidebar. It's fine if the image is distorted. Also, the title page is the first slide.

Comment: @Liz What about the height? Would you control it manually or do you want it to be equal to the headline's height?

Comment: @Gonzalo yes, it should be equal to the headline's height

Comment: @Liz OK. Give me a few minutes and I'll give you the required code.

Comment: @Liz Answer updated. Is it something like that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Gonzalo, yes that's perfect! thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Liz You're weclome! Glad I could help.